# How is the general solution for algebraic equations of degree five formulated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

In a book on neural networks I found the statement:

> The general solution for algebraic equations of degree five, for example, cannot be formulated using only algebraic functions, yet this can be done if a **more general class of functions** is allowed as computational primitives.

What are the "more general class of functions"?

Comment: This is a really cool question. Thanks for asking :)

Answer (score 15):

You can, for example, define an operation analogous to an $n$th root, except that instead of saying that $x=\sqrt[5] y$ if $x^5-y=0$, you say that $x=BR(y)$ if $x^5 +x -y=0$.

You can then express the solution of the general quintic in terms of $+, -,\times,\div,$ ordinary radicals, and $BR()$.

See [Bring radical](http://enwp.org/bring_radical) for more complete details, especially the section on [solution of the general quintic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Solution_of_the_general_quintic).

Answer (score 10):

Felix Klein has a small book called "Lectures on the icosahedron and the solution of equations of the fifth degree", where he develops a method of solving the quintic using modular forms. The relationship between the isocahedron and the general quintic is that the automorphism group of the isocahedron is $S_5$, which is also the Galois group of the general quintic.

Googling has turned up [this](http://ocfnash.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/on-kleins-icosahedral-solution-of-the-quintic/) introductory blog post on the topic, and [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.0955.pdf) expository article.